# What is the ritual that Rosalee and Monroe's mother performed?

Tags: grimm

In **Revelation** Monroe's parents object strongly to his choice of friends and love.  After several arguments Monroe's mother approaches Rosalee and asks if she "would be open to the (indistinct pseudo German word)".  Rosalee apparently agrees, and they approach and woge before the camera cuts away. This happens between 29:00 and 30:30.

What was the German word and what was its significance?

Answer (score 5):

The german word was vertrautheiten.  According to google translate it is the plural of the word familiarity, but vertrautheit also could translate as intimacy or closeness.